# Attachments without images

Tags: images, attachments, media

I am using the [Attachments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/) plugin, but this question I'm sure is applicable to the regular media library. What I want to do is have an 'attachment' (metadata, title, caption) but with no image associated with it. Reason being, I want to treat attachments as 'project items' which can either be an image or a block of text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use custom fields, attachments are for something to attach from your media library. 
Custom fields on the other hand can be anything you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

For a plugin I recommend , http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/